# Why it crashed when I try to do watershed delineation？

Tags: python-3.x, gis, qgis

I make a model in QGIS to do watershed delineation like this video：https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKdJMGXgOzg

And code of the model is like this：https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/b5sQ2jjSKR/

However when I run the model，it crashed like this：https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/SkDdnF2cPf/

And this is my DEM tiffs：https://postimg.cc/gallery/Q7xX8qT/104400c8

[[I want to delineate watershed in this yellow rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CapZq.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CapZq.png)

So how to solve my problem？

Comment: Do not put link to screenshots. You should include images directly in the question. This site is not a forum, but a reference site, so questions should be complete (and in this site, and without looking external links). Also: do you expect many people follows random links? And worse: you use pastebin: which has also a shorter life, and it is much easier to copy in the question. So I doubt you will have answers. (we are volunteers, so consider our resources).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now we use this to solve our problem:

https://github.com/xiejx5/watershed_delineation